# Finding SS - Regression - ANOVA

Tags: regression, self-study, anova

Hoping someone can guide me in the right direction here because I've exhausted all of the tools that were given to me by my professor and youtube.

Just to note: this is a practice problem and not homework. I have a ton of these types of questions, so if someone can explain this one to me, it'll greatly help me in answering the others. I was under the impression that when trying to find SS, I would be given values for X and Y and then I can find the mean and from there, compute the equation for SS $(Y_i (hat)-Y(mean))^2$ but nothing I try gets me remotely close to 582.63,the stated answer.
[image: i]

Comment: Whether it's a practice problem for a course or a homework problem, you are required to use the self-study tag.

Comment: got it, thanks, I just updated the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the standard error of the residuals ($s$) here is 
$$
s = \sqrt{\frac{SS_{\text{res}}}{n-2}} 
$$
You have $s$ (from the summary) and $n=20$, so you can calculate $SS_{\text{res}}$.

The formula for the $R^2$ is 
$$
R^2 = 1 -\frac{SS_{\text{res}}}{SS_{\text{tot}}}
$$
from which
$$
SS_{\text{tot}} = \frac{SS_{\text{res}}}{1-R^2}
$$
which gives the correct answer of 582.6355

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! makes sense that I couldn't get it since my prof never gave me these formulas.